# How to aggregate data based on consecutive row values?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am doing data analysis of photos of animals from trail cameras. My data includes what camera a picture was taken with, the date and time the picture was taken, and the animal in the photo. I wish to aggregate my data based on the time animals spent in front of the camera. For our purposes, an encounter is anytime we photograph an animal more than 10 minutes after photographing another of the same species. Encounters can be more than 10 minutes long in some cases, such as if we took 3 pictures of the same animal 7 minutes apart from one another, a 21 minute encounter. I want my output to aggregate my data into individual encounters for all animals photographed, and include start times and end times for each encounter photo series.

---

My code thus far

```
library(dplyr)

#Data 
df <- structure(list(camera_id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), date = c("11-May-21", "11-May-21", "11-May-21", 
"15-May-21", "15-May-21", "10-May-21", "10-May-21", "12-May-21", 
"12-May-21", "12-May-21", "12-May-21", "12-May-21", "13-May-21", 
"13-May-21"), time = c("5:23:46", "5:23:50", "5:32:34", "9:35:20", 
"9:35:35", "23:11:16", "23:11:17", "11:06:08", "11:15:09", "11:24:10", 
"2:04:01", "2:04:03", "1:15:00", "1:15:50"), organism = c("mouse", 
"mouse", "bird", "squirrel", "squirrel", "mouse", "mouse", "woodchuck", 
"woodchuck", "woodchuck", "mouse", "mouse", "mouse", "mouse")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))

#Combining date and time
df$datetime <- as.POSIXct(paste(df$date, df$time), format ="%d-%B-%y %H:%M:%S")

#Time differences in minutes, based on organism
df <- df %>% group_by(organism) %>%
  mutate(timediff = (datetime - lag(datetime))/60
  )

#Round minutes to 2 decimal points
df$timediff <- round(df$timediff, digits=2)

#Make negative and NA values = 0. Negative values appear when going from one camera to the next. R thinks it is going back in time, rather than 
#swapping cameras
df$timediff[df$timediff<0] <- 0
df$timediff[is.na(df$timediff)] <- 0
```

---

At this point, I want to use timediff as my condition for aggregation, and aggregate any subsequent rows of data with a timediff < 10, as long as the row has the same camera_id and organism. I've been trying different dplyr approaches but havent been able to crack this. The output should look like this.

```
structure(list(camera_id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), start_datetime = c("5/11/2021 5:23", 
"5/11/2021 5:32", "5/15/2021 9:35", "5/10/2021 23:11", "5/10/2021 11:06", 
"5/12/2021 2:04", "5/13/2021 1:15"), end_datetime = c("5/11/2021 5:23", 
"5/11/2021 5:32", "5/15/2021 9:35", "5/10/2021 23:11", "5/10/2021 11:24", 
"5/12/2021 2:04", "5/13/2021 1:15"), organism = c("mouse", "bird", 
"squirrel", "mouse", "woodchuck", "mouse", "mouse"), encounter_time = c("0:00:04", 
"0:00:00", "0:00:15", "0:00:01", "0:18:00", "0:00:02", "0:00:50"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this gets you your desired result:

A couple key changes: when we calculate `timediff` it makes sense to group by `camera_id` in addition to `organism`, since that grouping persists throughout.

Then, we need to create some helper columns to generate our grouping based on the 10 second condition.

`under_10` is 0 for all values of `timediff` less than 10, and also when `timediff` is `NA` (when a row is the first within the group). Under 10 is 1 when `timelapsed` > 10.

Then we create a grouping variable that increments when time elapsed is > 10. Then we simply summarize, calculating start and end based on min/max datetimes, and remove the grouping column.

```
library(tidyverse)

df$datetime <- as.POSIXct(paste(df$date, df$time), format ="%d-%B-%y %H:%M:%S")

#Time differences in minutes, based on organism
df <- df %>% group_by(organism, camera_id) %>%
  mutate(timediff = (datetime - lag(datetime))/60
  )

#Round minutes to 2 decimal points
df$timediff <- round(df$timediff, digits=2)

df %>% mutate(under_10 = ifelse(timediff < 10 | is.na(timediff), 0, 1)) %>% 
  arrange(camera_id, datetime) %>%
  mutate(grouping = cumsum(under_10)) %>%
  group_by(camera_id, organism, grouping) %>% 
  summarize(start_datetime = min(datetime), end_datetime = max(datetime),
    encounter_time = end_datetime-start_datetime) %>%
  select(-grouping)



camera_id organism  start_datetime      end_datetime        encounter_time
      <int> <chr>     <dttm>              <dttm>              <drtn>        
1         1 bird      2021-05-11 05:32:34 2021-05-11 05:32:34    0 secs     
2         1 mouse     2021-05-11 05:23:46 2021-05-11 05:23:50    4 secs     
3         1 squirrel  2021-05-15 09:35:20 2021-05-15 09:35:35   15 secs     
4         2 mouse     2021-05-10 23:11:16 2021-05-10 23:11:17    1 secs     
5         2 woodchuck 2021-05-12 11:06:08 2021-05-12 11:24:10 1082 secs     
6         3 mouse     2021-05-12 02:04:01 2021-05-12 02:04:03    2 secs     
7         3 mouse     2021-05-13 01:15:00 2021-05-13 01:15:50   50 secs
```

Also, if you'd rather have the H:MM:SS format for `encounter_time` you can get here like this, adding the following after the `summarize` call in the above code:

```
library(lubridate)
  ...
  mutate(encounter_time = seconds_to_period(as.character(encounter_time))) %>%
  select(-grouping) %>%
  mutate(encounter_time = sprintf("%1i:%02i:%02i", 
    lubridate::hour(encounter_time), 
    lubridate::minute(encounter_time), 
    lubridate::second(encounter_time)))

  camera_id organism  start_datetime      end_datetime        encounter_time
      <int> <chr>     <dttm>              <dttm>              <chr>         
1         1 bird      2021-05-11 05:32:34 2021-05-11 05:32:34 0:00:00       
2         1 mouse     2021-05-11 05:23:46 2021-05-11 05:23:50 0:00:04       
3         1 squirrel  2021-05-15 09:35:20 2021-05-15 09:35:35 0:00:15       
4         2 mouse     2021-05-10 23:11:16 2021-05-10 23:11:17 0:00:01       
5         2 woodchuck 2021-05-12 11:06:08 2021-05-12 11:24:10 0:18:02       
6         3 mouse     2021-05-12 02:04:01 2021-05-12 02:04:03 0:00:02       
7         3 mouse     2021-05-13 01:15:00 2021-05-13 01:15:50 0:00:50
```

However you end up with `encounter_time` stored as character, so that may or may not be useful

Comment: In lines `7` and `8`, there appears to be an error.  The 7th encounter ends at 1:15:00, and the 8th begins only 50 seconds later at 1:15:50.  Since the 8th began under 10 minutes after the 7th ended, shouldn't the 8th be "absorbed into" the 7th, as a single encounter from 1:15:00 to 1:15:50?

Comment: @Greg good catch, thank you! Updated the way the group is defined to address that.

Comment: Works brilliantly, and thanks for the extra formatting on encounter time. This is a much better approach than the things I had tried. Thanks so much!

Comment: You're welcome, glad to hear this was helpful and solved your problem!